# Скачок памяти на хостинге при установке nodeJS

Tags: linux, node.js

Дошли наконец руки попробовать установить все более популярный среди разработчиков nodeJS на свой маленький виртуальный хостинг с CloudLinux и cPanel. Делал пошагово через Putty как описано по ссылке https://hostpro.ua/blog/kak-ustanovit-nodejs-grunt-i-bower-v-svoy-akkaunt-cpanel/ но дойдя собственно до этапа самой установки сразу столкнулся с проблемой. В какой то момент процесс установки исчерпал максимальный лимит использования ввода-вывода (10 МБ) и физической памяти (512 МБ), после чего установка nodeJS остановилась.

Это происходит в момент когда в консоли доходит до

> -c -o /home/vikna211/node/out/Release/obj.target/v8_base/deps/v8/src/api.o ../deps/v8/src/api.cc

До этого все протекает нормально, но в момент появления этих строк I/O и память резко подскакивают к лимитам и процесс останавливается. Потом в консоли пишет:

> make[1](https://hostpro.ua/blog/kak-ustanovit-nodejs-grunt-i-bower-v-svoy-akkaunt-cpanel/): 
>   [/home/vikna211/node/out/Release/obj.target/v8_base/deps/v8/src/api.o]
>   Interrupt make[1](https://hostpro.ua/blog/kak-ustanovit-nodejs-grunt-i-bower-v-svoy-akkaunt-cpanel/):  Deleting intermediate file
>   `4095d8cbfa2eff613349def330937d91ee5aa9c9.intermediate' make: 
>   [node] Interrupt

Вопрос: можно ли как то сделать чтобы I/O и память во время установки node.js использовались умеренно, пусть процесс дольше длиться, но чтобы он успешно завершился?

Или может проблема не в том что памяти маловато. Может процесс пытается удалить тот intermediate file но не может и это вызывает резкий скачок обоих ресурсов к лимиту?

Comment: А на этот сервер какой-то другой пакет можно установить, не nodejs, а например mysql? Очень сильные ограничения у вас.

Comment: Его можно не устанавливать, а скопировать.

Comment: Что именно скопировать и как?

Comment: Всё скопировать... Не знаю.

Comment: @Qwertiy, собрать NodeJS из исходников со статическим линком всех либ и скопировать на сервер?

Comment: @AlexanderZonov, а уже собранный скатать нельзя? Там же zip-архив есть на сайте?

Comment: https://github.com/nodejs/help/wiki/Installation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда я устанавливал себе NodeJs на Debian 8, мне хватило 2-х команд:

1) `curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.8/install.sh | bash` - устанавливаем nvm https://github.com/creationix/nvm

2) `nvm install 8.9.4` - можно указать любую другую версию

Все. Сервер чистый, без панелей.

Comment: Почитал инструкцию у Вашего провайдера, там они используют `Wget`. На сайте nvm есть инструкция установки и с помощью этой штуки:`wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.8/install.sh | bash` Посмотрите сами. П.С.: я не специалист в этих вопросах. Только учусь